# Ubuntu 22 cannot find .NET Core

Tags: .net, .net-core

When I run `dotnet build`, I get

```
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.305/dotnet.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.8' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=7.0.8&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64
```

but when I run `dotnet --info` I get

```
$ dotnet --info
You must install or update .NET to run this application.

App: /usr/share/dotnet/sdk/7.0.305/dotnet.dll
Architecture: x64
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '7.0.8' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/share/dotnet/

No frameworks were found.

Learn about framework resolution:
https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed

To install missing framework, download:
https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=7.0.8&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.22.04-x64

Host:
  Version:      7.0.5
  Architecture: x64
  Commit:       8042d61b17

.NET SDKs installed:
  6.0.411 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]
  7.0.305 [/usr/share/dotnet/sdk]

.NET runtimes installed:
  No runtimes were found.

Other architectures found:
  None

Environment variables:
  DOTNET_ROOT       [/usr/lib/dotnet]

global.json file:
  Not found

Learn more:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/info

Download .NET:
  https://aka.ms/dotnet/download
```

My projects are using .NET Core 6, but I have `"DOTNET_ROLL_FORWARD": "Latest"` in my `launch.json`.

How can the SDK be installed but no runtimes -- but they are because I can run `dotnet --info`.

I did notice that when I run `which dotnet` I get `/usr/bin/dotnet` and that is different than the value of `DOTNET_ROOT`, but I don't know if that's something else.

What's weirder, is this has been working - it just started doing this and I cannot figure it out.

The `https://aka.ms/dotnet/app-launch-failed` URL was not helpful.

Comment: did it happen after any update you are aware of ?

Comment: Nothing I can think of. I wound up doing a purge of every installation and re-installed only 6 with apt. That fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I also encountered the same issue.

Initially, I installed the .NET environment, according to the Microsoft instructions:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/install/linux-ubuntu#register-the-microsoft-package-repository

Then I used this command:

```
sudo apt install aspnetcore-runtime-7.0 aspnet-runtime-7.0 dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

But after some time it stopped working and was complaining about the missing framework:

```
No frameworks were found.
```

Last time I removed dotnet and installed it again, and it helped me.

But now I encountered that issue again, and I suspect that there is some incompatibility between the dotnet SDK and environment. So, when the SDK is updated and the runtime has an older version, it stops working.

This time, I downloaded the runtime here as the terminal output suggests:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/7.0

Then I manually replaced all the files in the `/usr/share/dotnet` folder. And it is working for me again.

I confirm that the workaround instantly helps me even without rebooting the system.

**Update!**

I tried to use the answer below from QINGCHARLES:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/76617013/9316564

Since then, I no longer need to manually replace the dotnet files.

Answer (score 3):

This is the combination I used to fix this issue tonight:

```
sudo apt remove --purge --autoremove *dotnet*
```

then

```
sudo sh -c "cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/dotnet <<'EOF'
Package: dotnet*
Pin: origin packages.microsoft.com
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF"

sudo sh -c "cat > /etc/apt/preferences.d/aspnet <<'EOF'
Package: aspnet*
Pin: origin packages.microsoft.com
Pin-Priority: 1001
EOF"
```

then

```
sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0
```

Taken from here:

https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/27129

https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/7699

Comment: > sudo apt install dotnet-sdk-7.0
runs fine
> dotnet --list-sdks
shows nothing at all.  very frustrating

Answer (score 2):

By default DotNet core is installed in /usr/lib/dotnet directory.

```
Framework: 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '8.0.0' (x64)
.NET location: /usr/lib/dotnet
```

But its libraries are located in /usr/share/dotnet directory.

```
dotnet --list-runtimes

Microsoft.AspNetCore.App 8.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.AspNetCore.App]
Microsoft.NETCore.App 8.0.0 [/usr/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

You should create symbolic link of libraries folder to merge libraries and dotnet runtime.

```
sudo ln -s /usr/share/dotnet/shared /usr/lib/dotnet
```

Now it is run! That is fun!

```
/home/anvar/Documents/Bilimdon/Zakovat/bin/Debug/net8.0/Zakovat
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5056
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /home/anvar/Documents/Bilimdon/Zakovat
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
```